# deleting rows will improve select performance in oracle?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

i have a huge table (200mln records). about 70% is not need now (there is column ACTIVE in a table and those records have value N ). There are a lot of multi-column indexes but none of them includes that column. Will removing that 70% records improve SELECT (ACTIVE='Y') performance (because oracle has to read table blocks with no active records and then exclude them from final result)? Is shrink space necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really impossible to say without knowing more about your queries.

At one extreme, access by primary key would only improve if the height of the supporting index was reduced, which would probably require deletion of the rows and then a rebuild of the index.

At the other extreme, if you're selecting nearly all active records then a full scan of the table with 70% of the rows removed (and the table shrunk) would take only 30% of the pre-deletion time.

There are many other considerations -- selecting a set of data and accessing the table via indexes, and needing to reject 99% of rows after reading the table because it turns out that there's a positive correlation between the required rows and an inactive status.

One way of dealing with this would be through list partitioning the table on the ACTIVE column. That would move inactive records to a partition that could be eliminated from many queries, with no need to index the column, and would keep the time for full scans of active records down.

If you really do not need these inactive records, why do you just not delete them instead of marking them inactive?

Edit: Furthermore, although indexing a column with a 70/30 split is not generally helpful, you could try a couple of other indexing tricks.

For example, if you have an indexed column which is frequently used in queries (client_id?) then you can add the active flag to that index. You could also construct a partial index:

```
 create index my_table_active_clients
 on my_table (case when active = 'Y' then client_id end);
```

... and then query on:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  (case when active = 'Y' then client_id end) = :client_id
```

This would keep the index smaller, and both indexing approaches would probably be helpful.

Another edit: A beneficial side effect of partitioning could be that it keeps the inactive records and active records "physically" apart, and every block read into memory from the "active" partition of course only has active records. This could have the effect of improving your cache efficiency.

Comment: Actually, in that table there are records for each client. There is index on CLIENT_ID column which is used in my query. But in query I have also condition ACTIVE=Y (table has about 70% no active records and my index is not created on ACTIVE column). So I think we are talking about third option 'There are many other considerations'. Is my approach correct? Deleting these rows everyday will improve my query?

Comment: It's probably most fair to say that there are some queries which will be affected, and some which aren't.

Comment: Presumably a record only changes from active to inactive once, and then never changes again. It would almost certainly be worth the overhead of the row moving between partitions unless the operation that changes rows from active to inactive is extremely performance sensitive.

Comment: Which option for you is better: putting table in new list partitioned table or adding index?

Comment: I would definitely partition, if I had the license for it.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning, putting the active='NO' records in a separate partition, might be a good option.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/parpart.htm

Comment: I will consider it. Enabling ROW MOVEMENT will require deleting and inserting data in case of updating ACTIVE flag, yes?

Comment: Not really, updating the partitioning key will result in moving the record to another physical location (partition). Yes, there will be some overhead on DML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will most likely. But depending on your access schema the increase will most likely not as big. Setting an index including the column would be a better solution for future IMHO.

Comment: And gather statistics with histograms on that column

Comment: Yepp. But this is very basic ;)

Comment: Ok, but if I delete records with ACTIVE=N everyday (eg. using job) and do not create index on active column, Will it be ok?

Comment: If you (or anyone else in your company) don't need the information in these records ... But that's a functional question

Comment: A histogram could be counterproductive if bind variables are in use. Indexing might be useful, but with a 70/30 split it's unlikely to be used except for a bitmap merge with other indexes.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Cost of bind peak will be to high?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably no. Delete will not reduce the size of the table's segment. Additional maintenance might help. After the `DELETE` execute also:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> SHRINK SPACE COMPACT;
ALTER INDEX <indexname> SHRINK SPACE COMPACT;  -- for every table's index
```

Alternatively you can use old school approach:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> MOVE; 
ALTER INDEX <indexnamename> REBUILD;
```

When delting 70% of table also consider possible solution CTAS (create table as select). It will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing plays a vital role in SELECT query. The performance will drastically increase
if you use those indexed columns in the query. Ya deleting rows will enhance the                  performance 
for sure somewhat but not drastically.